# Non-reflective way to set properties of a type known at compile time

Tags: c#, types, reflection

I am working on a project that requires a  user to be able to modify properties of an object within a certain list of types, known at compile time.

For example, say I have a type defined by

```
public class A
{
   public float foo;
}
```

To set properties without reflection at near-native speeds during runtime (which is necessary for the project), I used a C# script which enumerates through the properties using reflection to generate code that looks something like this, which is then compiled.

```
public void Set(A obj, string path, object value)
{
    switch (path)
    {
        case "foo":
            obj.foo = (float)value;
            break;
    }
}
```

This works fine for simple types, but for more complex types, specifically where struct properties are its members, it becomes more difficult.

```
public class B
{
    public C foo { get; set; }
}
public struct C
{
    public float bar;
}
```

The code generated by this system no longer works, because accessing the struct property creates a copy.

```
public void Set(B obj, string path, object value)
{
    switch (path)
    {
        //...
        case "foo.bar":
            // Cannot modify the return value of 'C.bar' because it is not a variable
            obj.foo.bar = (float)value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, what I can do is modify the system to create a temporary struct variable, modify the member I want to access, and set the property's value to the temp variable, like so.

```
public void Set(B obj, string path, object value)
{
    switch (path)
    {
        //...
        case "foo.bar":
            C tmp = obj.foo;
            tmp.bar = (float)value;
            obj.foo = tmp;
            break;
    }
}
```

This system has several problems though. Nested struct properties would be hell to unwrap, and I would have to check every single parent property to ensure a setter method exists. This seems unnecessary and cumbersome, but I don't see any other option.

Is there a way that I can set property values for an object from a string path without runtime reflection?

Comment: Can you just use a rolsyln c# script? `await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("...", globals: obj, globalType: typeof(B))`, or maybe try to reuse some type of model binding like MVC?

Comment: if you have time, i recommend using interface for the structure on this one.. beside from reflection, using interface is another approach i know to handle such anonymous types..

anyway hope will help and give you some idea..

Comment: The issue is that I don't have access to these types; the B class is an example

Comment: Have you tried PostSharp or other aspect oriented approaches?